# How do I unconditionally exit a Dart application?

Tags: dart

In a server-side VM app, with a few Futures which may or may not return.  How to unconditionally exit the app?

Comment: That's a good question I see no Thread.exit() anywhere in the VM docs. Would throwing a exception be a unacceptable solution ?

Comment: Seth opened a bug to get this into a lib with better exposure: http://www.dartbug.com/3178

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To exit the VM:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  exit(0); // or non-zero for some error code
}
```

Which is documented [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io.html#exit). Thanks for asking!

Comment: Here you can see how it's used by `pub`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360809

Comment: This no longer links to this function, which doesn't seem to work anymore.