# What are the return codes for the Dart pub tool

Tags: dart, error-code, dart-pub

I'm going to be launching "pub get" and "pub build" iteratively in a batch file, and I need to test the return codes for errors.  The return codes don't seem to be documented in the Dart docs.  Does anyone know what they are, or where they're documented?

Comment: Never mind.  Simple sleuthing revealed that errorlevel=0 is success, errorlevel=1 is error.

Answer (score 6):

I found these:

- search in [pub.dart](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/bin/pub.dart) for 'exit_codes' to see which constants are used
- the constant values are defined here: (copied from [exit_codes.dart](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/exit_codes.dart))

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2012, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

/// Exit code constants. From [the BSD sysexits manpage][manpage]. Not every
/// constant here is used, even though some of the unused ones may be
/// appropriate for errors encountered by pub.
///
/// [manpage]: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sysexits
library pub.exit_codes;

/// The command completely successfully.
const SUCCESS = 0;

/// The command was used incorrectly.
const USAGE = 64;

/// The input data was incorrect.
const DATA = 65;

/// An input file did not exist or was unreadable.
const NO_INPUT = 66;

/// The user specified did not exist.
const NO_USER = 67;

/// The host specified did not exist.
const NO_HOST = 68;

/// A service is unavailable.
const UNAVAILABLE = 69;

/// An internal software error has been detected.
const SOFTWARE = 70;

/// An operating system error has been detected.
const OS = 71;

/// Some system file did not exist or was unreadable.
const OS_FILE = 72;

/// A user-specified output file cannot be created.
const CANT_CREATE = 73;

/// An error occurred while doing I/O on some file.
const IO = 74;

/// Temporary failure, indicating something that is not really an error.
const TEMP_FAIL = 75;

/// The remote system returned something invalid during a protocol exchange.
const PROTOCOL = 76;

/// The user did not have sufficient permissions.
const NO_PERM = 77;

/// Something was unconfigured or mis-configured.
const CONFIG = 78;
```